# Why is the standard deviation for this data zero, and what does that imply?

Tags: standard-deviation

I found the following data for 1000 rolls of a 20-sided die by a dice program:

```
[38, 53, 47, 42, 58, 42, 47, 56, 48, 57, 49, 49, 47, 45, 43, 49, 52, 55, 62, 61]
```

(Where the first value is number of times 1 was rolled, second value is number of times 2 was rolled, etc.)

I, a stats-know-nothing, tried to calculate the standard deviation for this and was surprised to come up with zero. I thought that was only possible if all the values were identical, but apparently that's not the case.

The reason I'm confused is that the calculation doesn't let me make a statement like "X% of die roll values come up within Y of the mean, while W% of die rolls only come up within Z of the mean." And I thought that was the point.

(to fill in a more specific value, e.g., I was expecting to be able to say something like "with a mean of 50 for how many times a given value is rolled, 68% of roll values appear within +/- 5 times of the mean, while 95% of die rolls come up within +/- 10 of the mean.")

What am I misunderstanding? Why do I only get zero and then have no further insights?

Comment: How exactly did you compute the standard deviation?

Comment: I misinputted something somewhere. Re-running it gives 6.44. I should have checked my math before asking at all. My mistake.

Comment: Well, not a waste.  With follow-up via Comments, maybe you resolved some other misunderstandings. Hope so.

Comment: You sound like you are trying to invoke a rule based off the normal distribution in your second last paragraph but it's not going to work that well for something close to a discrete uniform, though it should work okay for the counts within a category - but for which you need a different sd calculation. Incidentally, since the counts are fairly flattish across the outcomes, you should get something close to $\sqrt{(20^2-1)/12}\approx 5.77$ for the standard deviation of the 1000 rolls, perhaps just a little higher because of the tilt up toward high values

Answer (score 7):

An elaboration of @Dave's Answer (+1): You have data in 'frequency-value` format. (It is more compact than listing the $n=1000$ individual die faces observed.) If the $k = 20$ values are
$v_i = i,$ for $i=1$ through $k.$ and the corresponding frequencies
are $f_i,$ then the sample size is $n = \sum_{i=1}^k f_i,$ the sample mean
is $A = \bar X = \frac 1n\sum_{i=1}^k f_iv_i,$ the sample variance
is $S^2 = \frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^k f_i(v_i - a)^2,$ and the sample
standard deviation is $S = \sqrt{S^2}.$

In R:

```
f=c(38, 53, 47, 42, 58, 42, 47, 56, 48, 57, 
    49, 49, 47, 45, 43, 49, 52, 55, 62, 61)
n = sum(f);  n
[1] 1000
v = 1:20
a = sum(f*v)/sum(f);  a
[1] 10.843
s.sq = sum(f*(v-mu)^2)/(n-1)
[1] 33.84219
s = sqrt(s.sq);  s
[1] 5.817404
```

Based on these data you could make a 95% confidence interval for
the true population mean $\mu$ of the form $\bar X \pm 1.96\sigma/\sqrt{n}.$ In particular, $10.843 \pm 1.96(5.8174)/\sqrt{1000}$ or $(10.48, 11.20),$ which does include
the true value $\mu = 10.5,$ see theoretical computation below.
[The idea of the "95%" is that, over the long run, for repeated samples of size $n = 1000,$ 95 in 100 confidence intervals will
include $\mu,$ as happened here.]

```
pm = (-1,1)
a + pm*1.96*s/sqrt(n)
[1] 10.48181 11.20419
```

Another simulated sample (from R) yields the 95% confidence interval $(9.98,10.69),$ which also includes $\mu = 10.5.$

```
set.seed(2020)
x = sample(1:20, 1000, repl=T)
a = mean(x);  a
[1] 10.334
s = sd(x);  s
[1] 5.751306
```

For a single roll of a fair 20 sided die, $\mu = E(X) = 10.5, 
\sigma^2 = Var(x) = 33.25,$ and $\sigma = SD(X) = 5.7663.$
Thus, the sample values for $n=1000$ rolls of this die are
a reasonable match to the theoretical values.

```
p = rep(1/20, 20)
v = 1:20
mu = sum(p*v);  mu
[1] 10.5
sgm.sq = sum(p*(v-mu)^2);  sgm.sq
[1] 33.25
sgm = sqrt(sgm.sq);  sgm
[1] 5.766281
```

For a million rolls the match is even closer (about two decimal places):

```
set.seed(823)
x = sample(1:20, 10^6, repl=T)
a = mean(x);  a
[1] 10.49616
s = sd(x);  s
[1] 5.764575
```

**Addendum** re Comments on distribution of mean of 1000 rolls
of your 20-sided die. The simulation shows results from a million 1000-roll experiments.

```
set.seed(1234)
a = replicate(10^6, mean(sample(1:20, 1000, rep=T)))
summary(a); sd(a)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  9.554  10.377  10.500  10.500  10.623  11.337 
[1] 0.1822281  # SD(A)
hist(a, prob=T, br=30, col="skyblue2")
 curve(dnorm(x,mean(a), sd(a)), add=T, col="red", lwd=2)
```

[image]

Comment: From talking to a friend I was led to the conclusion that using SDs isn't really even a good way of analyzing what's expected to be an approximately flat rather than normal distribution though (i.e. every value should ideally appear an equal number of times), and that the SD of this doesn't really tell us anything meaningful. Thoughts?

Comment: I don't think much of your friend's statistical analysis of the situation (or at least of what you quoted from him/her). The distribution of $\bar X$ from $n=1000$ tosses will be much closer to normal than than to a 'flat' uniform distribution for individual rolls of the die. So a confidence interval such as I showed in my Answer should be quite accurate. // See Addendum with figure.

Comment: SD still tells us the SD. We just can’t use the 69/95/99.7 rule when the data do not follow a normal distribution. (This is not in contrast to what Bruce said, which is correct for sample means, though I think you mean the distribution of the data themselves, not a distribution of sample means that you would use for hypothesis testing and confidence intervals (which would have an approximately normal shape).)

Comment: @temporary_user_name By "flat", you presumably mean "uniform". Uniform distributions and normal distributions are both two-parameter families of distributions. Both are uniquely identified by their mean and SD (if you know which family they're in). However, while uniform distributions *can* be identified by those parameters, it's generally easier to work with the upper and lower bounds of the range.

Comment: "Flat" is to me a fine, if perhaps unusual, name for a uniform distribution. It is used seriously in a much-neglected text Schmitt, S.A. 1969. _Measuring Uncertainty: An Elementary Introduction to Bayesian Statistics._ Reading, MA: Addison-Wesley. In practice I wouldn't use it without flagging "uniform" and "rectangular" as other names very commonly used.

Answer (score 6):

You made a calculation error, I suspect by not squaring terms.

$$\sqrt{\dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i -\bar{x})}{n-1}}$$

Does that look familiar? It’s the wrong formula. The correct formula is:

$$\sqrt{\dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i -\bar{x} )^2}{n-1}}$$

There’s this issue of $n$ vs $n-1$ in the denominator. Most people do it like I did it, though $n$ pops up from time to time. This has to do with competing properties of the variance estimator called *maximum likelihood* and *unbiasedness*, topics that are appropriate for a separate discussion.

**EDIT**

I think you should be summing over 1000, not over 20. If your first rolls go $18$, $11$, $7$, $18$, $3$, you would use those numbers, not a $2$ for getting $18$ twice.

Comment: Okay, l don't _think_ I did that, but you might well be right. Let me run it again.

Comment: What software are you using for this?

Comment: From the original array of values, the mean is 50. Subtracting the mean and squaring the result gives `[144, 9, 9, 64, 64, 64, 9, 36, 4, 49, 1, 1, 9, 25, 49, 1, 4, 25, 144, 121]`, whose mean is 41.6, the sqrt of which is............6.44. Wow. Idk how I got zero the first time. Wtf lmao

Comment: (I wasn't using software, I was doing it by hand....but now that you point that out, I went and used an SD calc online and it got 6.44 also.)

Comment: So now I'm left wondering whether an SD of 6.44 really means anything about dice rolls though. Who's to say whether that's a good distribution of randomness or not?

Comment: I do not think the original array is what you want to analyze. Please see my edit.